# Would a sequence that jumps between one number and ever increasing numbers (up to infinity) be considered as going to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

I am studying analysis 1 - so this is still some extremely beginner stuff. So please keep the terms in the most simple way possible, thank you.

If we were to have a sequence, lets say: 3, 1, 3, 4, 3 , 7, 3 , 10. Where every other element grows up to infinity. Would this sequence be considered as going up to infinity. My professor says no. If so, why?

Also, follow up question. Because it's too similar to this one:

If we were to have a sequence, let's say 1,2,4,3,7,4,10,5. Where odd numbered index element has +3 added from the previous odd numbered one, and evey even has +1. Would this sequence be considered as going to infinity? Professor said that yes.

Finally, do either of these sequences have a limit?

Comment: Do you know the definition of “going to infinity”? Can you write it out?

Comment: If you've figured out the definition that Zhen Lin asked, maybe you can focus on the idea of 'subsequences' and how they relate to the original sequence when it comes to 'approaching infinity'

Comment: The question of whether the 2nd sequence has a limit is a question of convention. We might write $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ (or $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$) and say the limit is infinity. Or, we might be uncomfortable with treating infinity as if it were a number, in which case we'd say the sequence has no limit.

Comment: (1/2) @Meow From what i know, a subsequence is any sequence we can build from a given sequence. So, we can build a subsequence from the first sequence that looks like (3,3,3,3,3...) and one that  is( 1,4,7,10,...). The first one converges to 3, and is bounded (both lower and upper), so the limit is 3. The second one is not not bounded, so the limit is infinity. And, i think, since not all of the limits (of the subsets) are the same, it doesn't converge, and since it doesn't converge it doesn't have a limit. So, sequence one is divergent and it doesn't have a limit (even infinity)

Comment: (2/2) @Meow Unlike the first sequence the other sequence has subsequences, lets say (1,4,7,10...) and (2,3,4,5...) Which both converge to infinity, so this sequence has subsequences which all share the same limit, infinity, so it goes to infinity?

I hope i'm understanding this right, i'm not sure tho. Please tell me if i'm on the right track.

Comment: @Teo you hit the nail right on the head! Later on in the course, using their precise mathematical definitions will hopefully clear things up even more :)

Answer (score 0):

Maths is all about precision. When you say a sequence goes to infinity or to some finite number, what exactly do you mean? How would you define "going to" in mathematical terms? These are the things where you should start analysis. Instead of looking for definition, you can may be try to think of a logical definition on your own and then compare it to the standard definition.

Here is the standard definition:

Given a sequence $\{x_n\}$, we say it converges to some $a$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists$ $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|x_n - a|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

As with any definition in mathematics, instead of getting lost into the notations, you should try to understand what it means. That $|x_n - a|<\epsilon$ means that the difference between $x_n$ and $a$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ but now notice "any" $\epsilon>0$ in the definition. It essentially means that no matter how small the $\epsilon$ is (say as small as $10^{-100}$) you can always find a natural number $N$ such that beyond $N$, the difference between $x_n$'s and $a$ becomes smaller than $\epsilon$.

At this point, it is good to look at an example.
Take the sequence $0.1$, $0.01$, $0.001 \ldots$ which you can also express as $\{x_n = 10^{-n}\}$ as $n$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$. We say this sequence goes to $0$ because if we take any $\epsilon>0$, for example $\epsilon = 10^{-10}$ and you can see that as you go beyond $n=10$, the difference between $x_n$ and $0$ is smaller than $\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon = 10^{-100}$, the difference gets smaller than $\epsilon$ beyond $n = 100$. Take $\epsilon = 10^{-1000}$, the difference gets smaller beyond $n = 1000$. It simply doesn't matter how small $\epsilon$ becomes, we can eventually find a number beyond which the difference gets smaller than $\epsilon$. This is the precise formulation of "going to" or what we call "convergence".

Now take another sequence $1$, $0.1$, $1$, $0.01$, $1$, $0.001\ldots$. Can you say this converges to $0$? It doesn't for take $\epsilon = 0.5$. Can you find a number beyond which the difference gets smaller than $0.5$? No, because no matter how far ahead you go into the sequence, there is always a term equal to $1$ and $1 - 0 \not< 0.5$, is it?

Now coming back to your problem, you are considering going to infinity which needs a slight modification into the definition I gave. But I suggest you look for that definition yourself and then compare it to this and think why it is the way it is and what's the reason behind those small modifications? Finally, test your examples with that definition and you will get all your answers.

Comment: You are giving the definition of a finite limit.  You should write the definition of what it means for the limit of a sequence to equal infinity.

Comment: That's why I said he should look for 
the definition of infinite limit by himself. It's only a small modification and shouldn't be difficult to understand once you understand finite limit.